# .htaccess file working on Localhost but working partially on Server

Tags: php, .htaccess

All links are redirected properly on localhost not on server.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^css/(.*\\.css) /combine.php?type=css&files=$1
RewriteRule ^js/(.*\\.js) /combine.php?type=javascript&files=$1

ErrorDocument 404 /module/error.php 

RewriteRule ^/?app/([^/\.]+)/$ /index.php?pl=$1  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?app/([^/\.]+)$ /index.php?pl=$1  [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^/?app/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/$ /index.php?pl=$1&type=$2  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?app/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ /index.php?pl=$1&type=$2  [L,QSA]



RewriteRule ^/?print/([^/\.]+)/$ /index.php?pl=$1  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?print/([^/\.]+)$ /index.php?pl=$1  [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^/?print/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/$ /index.php?pl=$1&type=$2  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?print/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ /index.php?pl=$1&type=$2  [L,QSA]




RewriteRule ^/?report/([^/\.]+)/$ /module/report/index.php?pl=$1   [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?report/([^/\.]+)$ /module/report/index.php?pl=$1   [L,QSA]



RewriteRule ^/?logout/$ /module/login/logout.php  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?logout$ /module/login/logout.php  [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^/?login/$ /module/login/index.php?page=login  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?login$ /module/login/index.php?page=login  [L,QSA]  

RewriteRule ^/?token/$ /module/token/index.php  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?token$    /module/token/index.php  [L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^/?sql/$ /class/adminer.php  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?sql$   /class/adminer.php  [L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^/?update/$ /module/update.php  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?update$   /module/update.php  [L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^/?backup$ /module/backup/index.php  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?db_backup$   /module/backup/db_backup.php  [L,QSA]
```

This above code redirects properly on localhost. On server, It works for some links,  not for all.For example, domain.com/app/estimate, it is not working.For /app/items, it is working. Please help me...

[image]

[image]

In First picture, redirection doesn't work.
In Second Picture , redirection works properly

File Structure:

```
Root
|
|-->index.php
|
|-->class
|   |
|   |-->conf.php
|   |
|   |-->functions.php 
|
|-->module
|   |
|   |-->reseller
|       |
|       |-->Estimate
|       |   |
|       |   |-->estimate.php
```

functions.php content:

```
function value_show($text, $name, $value, $type,$count) { 
    if($type=="checked") 
    { 
        return '$(\'input[name="'.$name.'"]       
            [value="'.$value.'"]\').prop(\'checked\',true);';  
    } 
    if($type=="array") 
    { 
        return 
  
 '$(\''.$text.'[name="'.$name.'"]\').eq('.$count.').val("'.$value.'");'; 
    }   
    if($type=="multiple") 
    { 
        return '$("'.$text.'[name=\''.$name.'\']").val(['.$value.']);';   
    }   
    
    return '$(\''.$text.'[name='.$name.']\').val("'.$value.'");'; 
  }
```

I have imported functions.php in conf.php having connection string which is imported in index.php like below

```
conf.php:
require("functions.php");

index.php

require("class/conf.php");
```

When I call function which is inside functions.php, from estimate.php,
Its giving the loading page. If I remove that function call, then it shows content of estimate.php.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? What does "it is not working" mean? And how is this related to PHP?

Comment: actually I am new to php.I am little bit confused.Its redirecting the url on localhost. And Why it does not work on server. And I add this project as subdomain. It shows loader only. It does not show the page content.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XAMPP or MAMP

They have .htaccess enabled and the server is actively reading that file.
To allow the server/apache2 to start reading the .htaccess file, you need to tell apache to enable allow .htaccess.

Get your favorite text editor out and head over to your apache config.

Find the root directory in the apache config.

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinnks
    AllowOverride All // AllowOverride All is what tells apache to check .htaccess first
    Require all granted
<Directory>
```

Comment: Hi sir. I have domain and subdomain. In public  html , I have one .htaccess file and In subdomain directory, I have another .htaccess file. For dmain website, its works perfectly. For subdomain directory, .htaccess works partially. How to find apache config on Cpanel?

Comment: I found that problem where occurs. Could you please help me?. I have function.php. outside that folder. its like utility function. When I call function from that file it shows loading page on server. But On localhost its working fine.

Comment: @Sowmiya I'm going to need a bit more info. Can you send me the error please. this could just be a simple permission issue

Comment: I found the mistake sir. It is by default parameter. In local host it works. In server it cause an error. Error is I didn't set default parameter. In function definition, I have used 4 parameter. But In function call , I used only 2 arguments. Then I set default paramter in function definition. It resolves the pblm. Thanks for your help sir.